# Using dynamically created strings to retrieve array information

Tags: java, android

At the moment I am working on an app using Android Studio.

Lets suppose I have 3 buttons, and these buttons are responsible for retrieving and displaying the same type information, e.g. clicking on a specific contact in your contact list. The difference being that each contact is unique.

I want to make it so that all of the buttons have the same `onClick` function, which creates a string specific to that button, which can then be used to get information from an array. so far I have;

```
public void contactDetails(View view)
{
    String tag = String.valueOf(view.getTag());
    String array_id = tag + "_array";
}
```

This is able to create the string that I want to use, the only problem being is that when I call;

```
String[] contact_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_id);
```

it doesn't work, seeing as the parameter for `getStringArray` is an int and not a string.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a solution? I know that a `switch` can be created to handle the different buttons being pressed, but i thought that my way of doing it might be easier to allow for the dynamic creation of more buttons.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest in this case, if that is what you really want to do, to use a HashMap or HashTable to store the data. This will easily allow you to use Strings as keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResources().getIdentifier` to get Array from resources using String name :

Get resource id of Array :

```
int arr_id = getResources().getIdentifier(array_id, "array", getPackageName());
```

Now get Array using `arr_id` :

```
String[] contact_array = getResources().getStringArray(arr_id);
```